# Nodejs Error "EPROTO" when using GitHub Webhook to forward to Jenkins using dockerimage

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, github-webhook

I'm using a jenkins server behind a firewall. I used smee-client [smee.io](https://smee.io/) to get the webhooks from GitHub through the firewall.

I used the dockerimage from [deltaprojects/smee-client](https://hub.docker.com/r/deltaprojects/smee-client). It is running and connects to smee.io/xyz to get the webhooks. But if GitHub sending a webhook (configured sending it to smee.io/xyz) it was successfull with a 200 Response.
But the smee-client ist throwing some EPROTO Errors from nodejs. (see output below)

Config Github webhook:
  Payload url https://smee.io/xyz
  Content type application/json
Enable SSL verification
* Send me everything
[*] active

Webhooks seems to work and get a 200 HTML Response

The smee-client is showing the following Error:

```
{ Error: write EPROTO 140483050982248:error:1408F10B:SSL 
routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version 
number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:788:14)
errno: 'EPROTO',
code: 'EPROTO',
syscall: 'write',
response: undefined }
{ Error: write EPROTO 140483050982248:error:1408F10B:SSL 
routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version 
number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:788:14)
errno: 'EPROTO',
code: 'EPROTO',
syscall: 'write',
response: undefined }
```

I tried to build the image myself but with the same result in Error massage.
I'm not that fammiliar with ssl certificates or even if this problem is related to ssl.
Maybe someone faced this problem as well and know a hint what i'm doing wrong? That would be really nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solved by forwarding from smee-client to jenkins with http:// instead of https://
This Error message was kind of misleading